# sharepoint 2010 files in database but not in site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm new at sharepoint and having and issue in an existing site, users are asking a link that appears to be there but is not any more, so looking in database table AllDocs and filtering by DirName I see the files in database but in sharepoint site does not exists so how can I fix this so it shows in the web site?

Thanks

Comment: You may have more luck posting here:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the solution I implemented if someone have a similar issue some time: I wrote a program that extract the files I needed from Content database (AllDocs and AllDocStreams tables) and save it to my computer, after that I uploaded the files again to sharepoint.

Comment: Good sleuthing ericko.  You are allowed and encouraged to post an answer to your own question, not just a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I implemented if someone have a similar issue some time: I wrote a program that extract the files I needed from Content database (AllDocs and AllDocStreams tables) and save it to my computer, after that I uploaded the files again to sharepoint.